What is the yield loss from TiO2 (Titanium) mineral to Titanium sponge using the kroll process?
It is known that the Kroll process is a very energy intensive process that is very inefficient. It is also known that the yield of the Kroll process is not great as well. It would be very helpful to know the yield loss from Ti mineral to Ti sponge.

Processing of Ti mineral is not a part of the Kroll process   ( TiCl4 + 2 Mg -> ti + 2 MgCl2 )
